# Local notification cancel for particular time period

Tags: ios, swift, local, uilocalnotification

I want to fire local notification on a particular time based just liked water notification.
Like user can set wake up time & go to bed time n drink water notification for every 2 hours so how can i set that between goto bed to wake up time my local notification won;t fire, other than that the notification will fire for every 2 hours..

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: You can't set notification by frequency. You have to give specific time. Like show notification at 9, 11, 1, 3, 5 etc. So you have full control on when to start and end. Also, beware there is a limit on how many local push notifications you can have per devices (all apps). So don't add/create notifications for days. Every time user opens your app. you can recreate next "x" notifications.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to **obtain the hours** in between the wake up time and sleep time with the frequency of what you wish your notification to fire off.

Firstly, you would need to function to create a local notification that repeats during a **particular hour everyday**.

```
func createNotification(title: String, body: String, hour: Int, repeats: Bool, identifier: String) {
    
    //calendar
    let calendar = Calendar.current
   
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
   
    content.title = title
    content.body = body

    let today = Date()
    
    let futureDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hour, to: today)
    
    let hourComponent = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: futureDate!)
    
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: hourComponent, repeats: repeats)
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: {(error) in })
}
```

Secondly, place this code in your viewDidLoad() or the place you wish to set the notifications. What I am doing here is obtaining the wakeup hour and sleep hour and then finding the number of notifications that has to be made using the frequency that I want by dividing the difference in hour with the frequency.

I end of by creating a for loop that creates the notification based on the time that I add to the wakeup hour. eg. First notification fires of at 6am + 1x2 = 8am, second notification fires of at 6am + 2x2 = 10am

```
    //calendar
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    
    //set the wakeup and sleep hour
    let wakeupHour = 6 //6am
    let sleepHour = 18 // 6pm
    
    //Obtain starting time using date components
    let wakeup = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, hour: wakeupHour)
    
    //Obtain ending time using date components
    let sleep = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, hour: sleepHour)
    
    //calculate the number of hours between the two time
    
    //obtain number of hour difference
    let hourDifference = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: wakeup, to: sleep)
    
    //how many hours do you want
    let frequency:Int = 2
    
    //how many notifications will there be between the wakeup and sleeptime
    let numberOfNotifications:Int = hourDifference.hour! / frequency
    
    //create the notifications
    for num in 1...numberOfNotifications {
        //hour that each notification will fire off
        let hour = wakeupHour + frequency * num
           createNotification(title: "Drink Up", body: "Drink Up", hour:  hour, repeats: true, identifier: "drink\(hour)")
    }
```

I'm still learning swift so this may not be the most efficient way of solving this problem but I hope this helps!